Excel - Increment a counter if data is found
I am working with some sports data and am attempting to dynamically pull game info into another excel sheet. I have created an excel formula that does mostly what I want but I want to see if I can change the behavior slightly. Here are some screenshots of the data and then I will explain what I am trying to achieve.
This first screenshot is a small sample size of some of the data I am working with. I have Air Force in bold as that is the example team that I will be using for the data pull.

Here is where I am pulling the data on another sheet in excel. The table on the left is the result I currently get, but the table on the right is the table format I am trying to achieve. Cell A1 is just used to run a compare to the "Schedule" sheet.

Here is the formula I am currently using:
=IFERROR(INDEX(Schedule!$A$1:$I$866,MATCH((AGGREGATE(15,3,((Schedule!$F$1:$I$866=$A$1)/(Schedule!$F$1:$I$866=$A$1)*ROW(Schedule!$F$2:$I$866))-ROW(Schedule!$F$1),ROWS($O$2:O2)))-1,Schedule!$A:$A,0),COLUMN(B$1)),"")

So the changes I know that will need to be done to make the 2nd table possible are the IF statement which I have one created and then to do the increment for the [k] value of the AGGREGATE formula only if IF statement is true.
Here is the logic I am doing for the IF statement:
=IF(XLOOKUP(1,((Schedule!$B$2:$B$30=$I9)*((Schedule!$F$2:$F$30=$A$1)+(Schedule!$G$2:$G$30=$A$1))),Schedule!$B$2:$B$30,"")=$I9,*PULL THE DATA*,*LEAVE DATA BLANK*)

So the current [k] increment value being used is ROWS($O$2:O2) which works fine but since 'Air Force' is no present during week 3 is just pulls the next available which is week 4.
How can I go about instead keeping a more static value that increments by 1 when the formula is actually ran?
I have changed the formula to this which then allows me to have static weeks and then pull starting from DATE rather than WK:
=IF(XLOOKUP(1,((Schedule!$B$2:$B$30=$I9)*((Schedule!$F$2:$F$30=$A$1)+(Schedule!$G$2:$G$30=$A$1))),Schedule!$B$2:$B$30,"")=$I9,IFERROR(INDEX(Schedule!$A$1:$I$30,MATCH((AGGREGATE(15,3,((Schedule!$F$1:$I$30=$A$1)/(Schedule!$F$1:$I$30=$A$1)*ROW(Schedule!$F$2:$I$30))-ROW(Schedule!$F$1),ROWS($O$2:O2)))-1,Schedule!$A:$A,0),COLUMN(C$1)),""),"")

So when week 3 comes around, since no data will be pulled for week 3, I need the [k] value of the AGGREGATE function not to increment.
Maybe I am going about this the wrong way, but this is what I was able to get close enough of my final goal of the data pull.
Any help is appreciated. Thank you.
UPDATE
Due to the weeks indeed being a static known data, I was able to adapt and use bugdrown's suggestion which looks to be working flawlessly.
=XLOOKUP($B2&$A$1,Schedule!$B$2:$B$30&Schedule!$F$2:$F$30,Schedule!$C$2:$G$30,XLOOKUP($B2&$A$1,Schedule!$B$2:$B$30&Schedule!$G$2:$G$30,Schedule!$C$2:$G$30,"",0),0)

Thank you!

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

Which version of Excel are you using?

Currently using version 2407

Assumptions:
A.) You want to return a complete schedule (home and away games) for a single team.
B.) "Bye" weeks should a show blank row.
Since the number of weeks in the season are known, set up your lookup table with the WK column filled in: =SEQUENCE(18)
In the lookup formula, set the lookup_value argument to a concatenation of WK and the team name. We'll nest XLOOKUP() formulas so that if an AWAY game doesn't exist for a WK, another XLOOKUP() will look up the concatenation of WK and team name in the HOME column, otherwise, return an empty string.
In my workbook, I named the sheet with the complete schedule as MasterSchedule and the schedule for the criterion team as TeamSchedule. I've located the team lookup_value in cell TeamSchedule!$I$2 (currently set to Air Force).
With WK data for the season filled in TeamSchedule!$A2:$19 using: =SEQUENCE(18) in TeamSchedule!$A$2, enter the following formula in TeamSchedule!B2 and drag it down through TeamSchedule!B19:
 =XLOOKUP($A2&$I$2,MasterSchedule!$B$2:$B$30&MasterSchedule!$F$2:$F$30,MasterSchedule!$C$2:$G$30,
          XLOOKUP($A2&$I$2,MasterSchedule!$B$2:$B$30&MasterSchedule!$G$2:$G$30,MasterSchedule!$C$2:$G$30,"",0)
  ,0)


I was able to adapt this to my spreadsheet and this works great! Thank you very much. Getting rid of the AGGREGATE function has made this much cleaner as well.

@Link Glad this helped. Thank you for the points and good luck with your project.
